# Permission for a MySQL user to perform Backups

Tags: mysql, backup, database

What permissions for a MySQL user would be enough to perform a full backup?

I use innobackupex which requires a password on the command line. So i wanted to create a user with not so much permissions granted like root, yet enough to perform a backup.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in http://www.fromdual.com/privileges-of-mysql-backup-user-for-mysqldump

for `mysqldump --single-transaction` You need: `SELECT, SHOW VIEW, RELOAD, REPLICATIOn CLIENT, EVENT` and `TRIGGER`

```
GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW, RELOAD, REPLICATION CLIENT, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO  'backup'@'localhost';
```

And for `mysqldump --lock-all-tables` you need: `LOCK`

```
GRANT LOCK TABLES ON *.* TO 'backup'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Thank you Paulo. But i have already figured out what permissions i need and posted them here: https://georgechilumbu.wordpress.com/2017/06/13/mysql-privileges-for-backups/